# VB2015 - DataGridView - Images in Specific Cells

Tags: vb.net, image, datagridview

I have the following problem: I want to import an excel file into my dgv (datagridview). If a cell(x,y) in the datasource carries a specific value, e.g. 2, the associated cell(x,y) in the dgv should display an image.

I used the following code:

```
For i = 0 To DataTable.Rows.Count - 1
   For j = 0 To DataTable.Columns.Count - 1

        If DGMatrixP1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = 2 Then
            DGMatrixP1.Rows(i).Cells(j).ValueType = System.Type.GetType("Bitmap")
            DGMatrixP1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = Image.FromFile("path to file")

        End If
   Next
Next
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error message "expected double" and "System.Drawing.Bitmap cannot be converted to System.IConvertible".

How can I fix this?

Addition: If I already have an populated dgv and I want to change the value of an cell from an integer to an image - even if i try to set the valuetype of the cell equal to the data type of a datagridviewimagecell, I get the error "DataGridViewTextBox cannot be converted to DataGridViewImageCell". How can I fix this?

Comment: As the error indicates, you cannot change the type of an individual cell.  The cell type is tied to the column type.

Comment: So it's impossible to have a column in my dgv which contains cells with integer values and cells with images?

Comment: Thats not quite what I wrote.  You could use the `CellFormatting` event to display whatever you want however you want. That code is odd though - it will act on *any* cell in *any* row with a value of 2.  That seems a bit broad.  Also you should not create a new image object for each cell - they can share

Comment: Thanks for your help. English ist not my first language, so I may have not been specific enough, but that's exactly what I want. Each cell with the value of 2 should display the same image. I wrote a private sub for the CellFormatting-Event, and set the value of the cell equal to the image on the filepath, but now I get the error message "Operator = is not defined for bitmap or integer".

Comment: Visual Studio/VB IDE will create the event handlers for you and hook them up as well.  Creating your own may not work unless you know how to wire them up.

Comment: Well I used the drop down menus on the top of the code editor window - selecting my dgv and "CellFormatting" - and it created: "Private Sub DGMatrixP1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DGMatrixP1.CellFormatting" with the correspronding "End Sub". So I'm not quite sure what I did wrong. To be more specific: the code runs without problems, the dgv gets displayed, but as soon as I change the value of any cell to 2 I get the error message instead of the cell display an image.